# How to display *help* buffers below one specific window?

Tags: ess, window-splitting, r, display-buffer-alist

I am (*really*) new in Emacs and ESS, and I am currently trying to customize my environment.
The default settings of ESS[R] are convenient for me, since ESS[R] organizes the windows as follows:

```
-----------------------------
|   ESS[R]    |    *R*      |
|  (R code)   | (R console) |
|             |             |
|             |             |
-----------------------------
```

But one thing I don't like is that, when you call an help page (or when using the `C-c C-v` shortcut), the default is to display the help page *instead of* the *R* buffer, like that:

```
-----------------------------
|   ESS[R]    |  *help[R]*  |
|  (R code)   |             |
|             |             |
|             |             |
-----------------------------
```

I would like the help buffer to be displayed just below the R buffer instead, like that:

```
-----------------------------
|   ESS[R]    |    *R*      |
|  (R code)   | (R console) |
|             |-------------|
|             |  *help[R]*  |
|             |             |
-----------------------------
```

But I don't manage to do that. I read carefully the manual, but I should have missed something. I added the following instructions in my `.emacs` file:

```
 '(display-buffer-alist
   (quote
    (("*Help"
      (display-buffer-at-bottom)
      (slot . 1)
      (side . right)
      (window-width . 0.5)))))
```

but it does not work, since the help buffer is displayed below the two other, with a width of 1.
What should I do to get the window organization I want?

Comment: One quick and simple way is to make `*Help*` a "special buffer" so it gets a dedicated window: customize option `special-display-buffer-names`, adding `"*Help*"` to it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Drew for your answer, but it did not work (maybe I did not made it correctly :-)). I tried to add this in my `.emacs` file:

```
(setq special-display-buffer-names
      '("*Help" "*help[R]*" "*Help*"))
```

but nothing changed. Then, I tried various settings for the variable `ess-help-frame-alist`, and I did not manage neither...

However, I finally found a solution! The following code is okay, and I think it was necessary to set the parameters of the *R* frame **before** the parameters of the *Help* frame:

```
(setq display-buffer-alist '(("*R"
                              (display-buffer-reuse-window display-buffer-in-side-window)
                              (side . right)
                              (slot . -1)
                              (window-width . 0.5)
                              (reusable-frames . nil))
                              ("*Help"
                              (display-buffer-reuse-window display-buffer-in-side-window)
                              (side . right)
                              (slot . 1)
                              (window-width . 0.5)
                              (reusable-frames . nil))))
```

Not so easy, but functional. :-)

Thanks again!

Comment: My recollection is that the `display-buffer-alist` uses regex for buffer names.  An asterisk is not a literal asterisk unless it looks like `\\*` or `[*]` -- there may be other forms for literals, but I'm not that fluent in reg-speak.  If your intention is to use the asterisk as something other than a literal asterisk, then just disregard my comment ...

Comment: @lawlist is correct in general, but `"*R"` and `"*Help"` will actually be working as intended, because certain metacharacters match literally when they appear in positions where their usual behaviour makes no sense.  In this instance `*` as the very first character of the regexp makes no sense as a metacharacter, and consequently it actually matches a literal `*`.  This behaviour is not very intuitive, however, and I would not recommend making intentional use of it -- it is cleaner to always use escaping in these situations, even if it's not strictly necessary.